# Independent matrix elements in non-linear optical tensors & point group

Tags: condensed-matter, group-theory, tensor-calculus, group-representations, non-linear-optics

There is a detail on the research of the number of independent matrix elements of a tensor in non linear optical phenomena that I don't understand. If we expand the polarizability $\vec{P}$ according to the electric field $\vec{E}$, we get 
$$\vec{P} = t^{(2)} \cdot \vec{E} + t^{(3)}\cdot \vec{E}\cdot\vec{E}+ \ldots ,$$
where $t^{(n)}$ is the tensor of a $n$ rank. I understand that to find the number of  independent matrix elements that there are in the tensor $t^{(n)}$, I have to found how many times the scalar representation appears in the decomposition of  $\Gamma_{\vec{P}} \times \Gamma_{\vec{E}^{n-1}}$.

For example, in the case of linear polarizability ($\vec{P}= t^{(2)} . \vec{E}$) of a crystal with a $O_h$ symmetry (character table below), this decomposition is
$$\Gamma_{\vec{P}} \times \Gamma_{\vec{E}}=\Gamma_{15}^{-} \times \Gamma_{15}^{-}=\Gamma_{1}^{+}+\Gamma_{12}^{+}+\Gamma_{15}^{+}+\Gamma_{25}^{+}. $$

Since $\Gamma_{25}^{+}$ is antisymmetric under interchange of $i\to j$, you have to remove it because the tensor $t^{(2)}$ is symmetric.

However, I don't understand **how to get the fact that $\Gamma_{25}^{+}$ is antisymmetric under interchange of $i\to j$ from the character table.** I guess it's from the basis of the representation but I don't know how exactly. Any help please?

I need to understand that because when you want to know the non-linear part of the polarizabilitty, you need this result to determine $\Gamma_{\vec{P}} \times \Gamma_{\vec{E}\vec{E}}$ and the $t^{(3)}$ tensor.

[image: Character Table Oh]

Source : *Applications of Group theory to the Physics of Solids*, M. S. Dresselhaus, Spring 2002